# Is output data normalization necessary in SVM regression?

Tags: regression, svm, normalization

We talk a lot about input data normalization, I want to know if output data normalization can do good to SVM regression, for example, maybe it could help to reduce grid search scope when doing cross-validation ? is there any discussion on that ? thanks a lot